# How do i get the current width of a Label in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a lable within a text and i want to get the current width of the Label

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="hello world!")
label.pack()

print("label width: ", label.winfo_width())

root.mainloop()
```

Here is an executable example of my problem, the method `.winfo_width()` always return 1. Has tkinter a method for get the real width of the label or i have to build it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proper way to get the width of a single widget is with the `winfo_width` method. It will return the width of any widget.

The important thing to know about `winfo_width`, however, is that it returns the *actual* width of the rendered widget. If it hasn't been rendered -- either you haven't placed it in a window or the window hasn't had a chance to be drawn -- it will return a width of 1 pixel.

In your case you can call `update` before getting the width. This will cause the window to be drawn on the display, resulting in a correct value from `winfo_width`.

```
root.update()
print("label width: ", label.winfo_width())
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get the width/height before using `pack()` or any other geometry managers?

Comment: @CoolCloud: `winfo_reqwidth()` and `winfo_reqheight()` will return the requested width and height. The actual width is indeterminate until it is added to the window with a geometry manager, since the geometry manager may grow or shrink the widget.

Answer (score 2):

```
    root.geometry("800x600")
```

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_width-method
Quoting the link it states:
winfo_width() [#]

Get the width of this widget, in pixels. Note that if the window isn’t managed by a geometry manager, this method returns 1. To you get the real value, you may have to call update_idletasks first. You can also use winfo_reqwidth to get the widget’s requested width (that is, the “natural” size as defined by the widget itself based on it’s contents).

Returns: The widget’s current width, in pixels.

Comment: `geometry` returns the width of the window as a whole, not a single widget inside the window. The result will be close to the size of the label if there's only a single label, but even then the returned size may be off a pixel or two depending on the default border of the window.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't specify correctly, what I meant was that if the windows does not have a geometry manager winfo_width return 1 by default, so in the code I just wrote root.geometry("800x600"). After that I stated the method would return the size of the widget.