# How to get width and height of the label in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to print the width and height of the label
But the result is always 356 156

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

label = tk.Label(root, text="Drag me!", width=50, height=8)
label.pack()

root.update()

width = label.winfo_width()
height = label.winfo_height()
print(width, height)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i get the current width of a Label in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55667841/how-do-i-get-the-current-width-of-a-label-in-tkinter)

Comment: I get `356 126` instead, but that's with a possibly different Tk version and platform so probably not meaningful.  Why do you think there's a problem with this?  The `width=` and `height=` parameters you're specifying for the Label are in terms of *characters* (unless it's displaying an image).  It would probably be clearer if you gave the Label a distinct background color, so you could see exactly what part of your window constitutes the widget's size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`width = 50` is saying is that the label will be 50 *characters* wide, not 50 *pixels* wide. `label.winfo_width()` returns the number of pixels of the width.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_label.htm

Comment: So, how can I get the width in the number of characters or how to set the width of the label in pixels, not the number of characters?

Comment: @BaRiboD You can approximate it with this:
`width_in_characters = label.winfo_width() // label.font.measure("0")`
This uses the width of the character "0" to approximate the character width, note that each character will have a different pixel width if you don't use an evenly spaced font.